# Determine whether object has rotation or is not uniform and reset it

Tags: transforms

I am very new to Blender. I am using 2.93.4 version.

I was creating a dormitory building, often pressing wrong combinations, selecting not the object I need and transform it, and making another mistakes.

Suddenly, I noticed that balcony does not "fit" the building properly:

[image]

I tried to rotate it, using mouse, but even holding `shift` or\and `control` key rotaion is not accurate. Then I noticed, rotate "widget" in bottom-left corner, where I set all x,y,z rotations of balcony and build to zero, but it still does not fit. **But**, in the same time, their vertical corners also are not parallel to 100% not rotated and uniform cube, that I created for testing.

So in my opinion there can be two issues: either I reset rotation wrong, or balcony's (or building's) surface is trapezoidal (or other) and not rectangular.

**My question** is how to check both and, mainly - **fix**.

Comment: It's located in the right bar in the 3d view, you can open it by pressing "t". You can reset a selected object's rotation by pressing "alt+r".

Comment: @FFeller it helped, thanks!